# Mongodb intermittent spikes in fetch latencies

Tags: mongodb, memory, latency, morphia

I am facing the issue of intermittent spikes in response latencies while fetching data in a sharded cluster. Data is always being queried via indexed fields.

Also seeing high CPU usage on secondary boxes (cpuUsage:99% loadAvg:2.5) at exact same time as the latencies.

Client: Morphia Client with ReadPreference = PRIMARY, ReadConcern = Local, WriteConcern Default. As per my understanding secondaries should not affect the response if ReadConcern is Local.

Is there any correlation here?

MongoDB version 4.2.2
mongod instance running on 8 core, 40 GB RAM machine, wiredtiger cache 11 GB.

Can anybody suggest what might be the issue or how to debug this?

Comment: Is cpu usage spiking? If yes, do spikes correspond to increased latency? Is the load on database server otherwise constant? What is memory used by since your WT cache only takes up 25% of it?

Comment: CPU usage is spiking only on secondaries and yes at the same moment as latencies, not sure as to how are they correlated. The only task of secondary is performing is replication. The load is otherwise constant to 0.1, spikes to 2.5 when this happens.
Memory used: 13G        free: 403M      buff/cache: 25G

Comment: Are queries that have increased latency being answered by secondaries?